# Controlling Height of Grid Item Image

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid container with 2 columns, one is autosized and the other fills in the rest of the space: `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;` The first column has an image grid item and the second column has a grid item that holds text. What I am trying to get is for the image's height to be the same as the height of the text grid item. I know that I could just hardcode the row height in pixels, and then give the image that pixel height. However, hardcoding the row height could be dangerous because the content can change and then might no longer fit. How could I avoid hardcoding the heights, but make sure that the image grid item takes up the entire height of its grid area (the same height as the text grid item)? I have tried giving the image grid item the `height: 100%;` style, but on all browsers, but chrome, this simply causes the image to return to its original size.

Example Code:

```
    <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .header-image {
        border: 2px solid green;
        grid-area: hdimg;
        height: 80px;
    }
    .header-text {
        border: 2px solid green;
        grid-area: hdtxt;
    }
    .container {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
        "hdimg hdtxt";
    }
</style>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img class="header-image" src="image.jpg">
        <div class="header-text">
            <h1>Some Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a prototype that you can attach to this question so that others can take a look and see the problem?

Comment: Yes, I just created an example. I will attach it now.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: I know this is kind of opinion based -- but I wouldn't use grid for the guts of the component ( component in this case being the header ) -- I would use something else like flexbox as it comes with some of the height conditions you would want.

My anecdotal rule of thumb is grid for page layout and flexbox for Components.

Totally off topic and not related to CSS-Grid but might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Even though I know that CSS grid is not intended for single dimensional layouts like the one above, I'm just trying to get accustomed to css grid as I am very new to it. I understand that making this type of layout would be very simple with flexbox

Comment: I guess what my question is really asking is how can I make allow the second column to auto-size based on content, but not allow the first column to autosize.